# Genji deflecting Sonic Arrow?

Tags: overwatch

Simple question: what happens when Genji deflects Hanzo's Sonic Arrow? Will Genji's team be able to see nearby enemies through walls like a normal Sonic Arrow would? Or does that effect stay with the Hanzo who fired the Sonic arrow?

Answer (score 6):

Any deflected attack belongs to the Genji's team, not the enemy's. A deflected Sonic Arrow will work for the Genji's team, not the Hanzo's.

Comment: The only semi-exclusion I know is Junkrat's mine which junk still has control over the detonation.

Comment: @ИвоНедев However, when such deflected mine is primed by Junkrat it damages him instead of Genji. At least that's what I think is happening.